# Excel summary of columns depending on an other column

Tags: excel

I would require some help regarding an excel document. I have a table with ~100 names and ~20 dates like this.

```
-------------------------------------
| Name0   |            |    Date2   |
-------------------------------------
| Name1   |    Date1   |            |
-------------------------------------
| Name2   |            |    Date2   |
-------------------------------------
| Name3   |    Date1   |    Date2   |
-------------------------------------
```

Every name may contain multiple dates, every column is one date.

My problem is that i want to create a summary like this:

```
---------------------------
|    Date1    |   Date2   |
---------------------------
|    Name1    |   Name0   |
---------------------------
|    Name3    |   Name2   |
---------------------------
|             |   Name3   |
---------------------------
```

The big name - date table get updated very frequently. I tried some `search`, and `if` --> `istext` combinations, but with every result so far i get back the empty cells as well, which is bad considering that on a 100 long name column for example on `date8` there may be only 5 `names`, but i get back 95 empty rows as well, and the 5 real `names` are scattered.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Di you try Pivot table on your data? If not give a try. I hope it should serve your purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my below screenshot, put this array formula to `E2` cell and Fill right (Drag and right).

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$5,SMALL(IF($B$1:$C$5=E$1,ROW($B$1:$C$5)),ROWS($A$1:$A1))),"")
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula.

**as it an array formula**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, checking it now

Comment: So "fill right" you mean i have to correct the formula for every ~100 name entry?

Comment: No. Fill right means for cell `F2`. When you will enter formula in `F2` cell then change date cell from `E$1` to `F$1`

Comment: You can also input formula manually to `E2` and `F2` then no need fill right.